# Extending Third Party Component in Angular into your own Custom Component

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I am trying to extend AgGrid Compoment into my Custom Grid Component

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'custom-grid',
      templateUrl: './grid.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./grid.component.scss'],
      providers:[AngularFrameworkOverrides, AngularFrameworkComponentWrapper]
    })
    
    export class CustomGridComponent extends AgGridAngular implements OnInit {
        
          constructor(private http: HttpClient, 
            elementRef : ElementRef, 
            viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, 
            angularFrameworkOverrides : AngularFrameworkOverrides,
            angFrameworkComponentWrapper : AngularFrameworkComponentWrapper,
            componentFactoryResolver : ComponentFactoryResolver) 
          {
            super(elementRef, viewContainerRef, angularFrameworkOverrides, angFrameworkComponentWrapper, componentFactoryResolver);
          }

...
```

Custom Grid Template is very simple and looks like this

```
<ag-grid-angular
   [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
   [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
   [rowData]="rowData$ | async"
   ></ag-grid-angular>
```

Now that its been inherited, I was expecting to simply supply some AgGrid specific properties ("animateRows") in my Custom Grid Component like so

```
<custom-grid [animateRows]="true"></custom-grid>
```

But this does not work. I can successfully access the Property on my Custom Grid and set it but it does not enable row animation in the rendered Grid.

I could create a @Input CustomAnimateRows: boolean in my Custom Grid Component and then use that in the Custom Grid Template like so

```
<ag-grid-angular
   [animateRows]="CustomAnimateRows"
 ></ag-grid-angular>
```

and it does work but that would mean I need to create an @Input property of each equivalent property on AgGrid which makes extending it useless. Can somebody explain whats the right way of extending a third party component into your own custom component? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Extending angular components by inheriting is tricky stuff. And overriding @Input fields is the easiest case. But I wouldn't call it useless.

Comment: you could check this article, very similar to your case: https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/use-angular-directives-to-extend-components-that-you-dont-own